# sftp file modifications not detected via FSEvents

Tags: macos, sftp, fsevents

On OSX 10.8.x, I am using FSEvents to detect changes in a directory.
The problem is that when a file is copied via sftp, the FSEvents callback is not called.
When I am using `cp` to copy a file (or `touch` to simulate a change), the callback is called.
Am I doing something stupid ? Is sshd using some sort of low level API to create the file ? Should I file a bug to Apple ?

```
eventQueue = dispatch_queue_create(EVENT_QUEUE_NAME, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

//Watch the data/apns directory (for .json files)
NSString *pathToWatch = ...
NSArray  *pathsToWatch = @[pathToWatch];
CFAbsoluteTime latency = 1.0; /* Latency in seconds */

// Create the FileSystem events stream, passing in a callback
streamRef = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                &fscallback,
                                NULL,
                                (__bridge CFArrayRef)(pathsToWatch),
                                kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                latency,
                                kFSEventStreamCreateFlagIgnoreSelf);
if (streamRef)
{
    FSEventStreamSetDispatchQueue(streamRef, eventQueue);
    if (NO == FSEventStreamStart(streamRef))
    {
        DDLogError(@"FSEventStreamStart error");
    }
    else
    {
        DDLogError(@"FSEventStreamStart ok");
    }
}
else
{
    DDLogError(@"FSEventStreamCreate error");
}
```

I am using internal-sftp in the sshd config:

```
...
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group users
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
Match User user
ChrootDirectory /vhosts/web/user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not doing anything wrong.  The problem relates to your use of a chroot; I was able to reproduce this without involving `sshd` at all, just by running `touch` in a chroot.

FSEvents is recording the events as occurring on the path in the chroot, e.g., `/foo` rather than `/vhosts/web/user/foo`.

This is almost certainly an OS X bug; whether you're going to get Apple to fix it any time soon is another matter.  Your best bet is probably to use Apple's sandboxing (run `sftp-server` with `sandbox-exec`) rather than a chroot.

Comment: It makes sense (kind of). But how do you know that the event is occuring on the chrooted path ? If that were the case, shouldn't I be able to get the events by watching the /foo path ? But it does not work.

Comment: /foo also has to exist in the base filesystem or the events won't be delivered.  Really, I don't think it's worth the effort to work around this bug.

Comment: You are right but now that you have put this idea in my mind, I would like to validate it so that all the time wasted on this would at least yield a logical explanation of twhat is going on.  I have created the /foo directory and I have gave it the right permissions and it still doesn't work. So my guess is it's just a weird edge case in Apple implementation.

Comment: Now I am heading to server fault because I have questions about sftp+sandbox-exec, although I should probably use kqueue.

Comment: All I can say is it worked for me on 10.8.4 (the exact directories I tried with are /private/var/tmp/net and /net).  Good luck :-)

Comment: I have several virtual hosts with the same directory structure, it may explain why it's not working for me.